# unable to configure network from marshmallow VM

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have installed marshmallow VM (virtual box) on ubuntu 14.04.
I was able to install with network settings off.
However if I go ahead and configure network settings as given below:

[image: network settings for marshmallow vm]

I am still unable to access google playstore or browser or anything where network is required.
It shows "unfortunately google playstore (or browser) has stopped working".
Can anybody help me how to fix this out ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting NAT in "Attached to" setting?

Comment: tried to do that and checked all the options present in it but nothing worked out.